# How to identify and delete corrupted files

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, file-corruption, filesystem-corruption

I've recently recovered a few hard-drives using partition and data recovery software. Most of the recovered data is intact, but amidst a total of 3TB of data, even a small percentage of corrupted files adds up to large figures.

These files consist of all of the major file formats: images, video/audio files, Word documents, PDFs and so on, and what I'm currently facing is going through each recovered folder and manually opening up each file to determine whether it's corrupted or not. This is easier on image file formats, for which the lack of a thumbnail is a giveaway that a file is corrupted, but for most other formats, like audio and video files, the files would need to be opened and played all the way through to determine there is no corruption. For obvious reasons, I'd rather not have to do this.

**What solutions are currently out there to allow me to search for corrupted files and remove them from my recovered hard-drives?**

Comment: "including non-software"? Are you expecting a hardware solution?

Comment: Edited to make clearer.

Comment: "If you are using data recovery software it means, the files were already deleted, because data recovery software doesn't recover "corrupt files" although the files the software might recover might be corrupt." Could you explain to me what exactly this means, cause I can't make head or tails of it.

Comment: I guess @Ramhound point is there is no strict and universal definition of "corruption" until you have an error detecting code (ZIP files do have those, for instance). Therefore there cannot be a magic tool that can tell corrupted files for sure, especially if you consider "all the major file formats".

Comment: Yes, the files *were* deleted, and then recovered by a data recovery tool, after which some of those files became corrupted, presumably because they'd already been partially overwritten on the disk. There is a universal definition of what file corruption means to most users; it's a file that exists in Explorer but won't open, and can therefore be reasonably considered to be lost. Windows image viewer displays a "damaged or corrupt" message instead of the images, PDFs and Word documents have in-application dialogue that does the same.

Comment: I thought this would be obvious to those on this site, which is why I didn't elaborate on what I meant by file corruption. Granted, I don't know what the software development nuances are, and whether it's technologically possible to programmatically detect this kind of corruption, but I didn't think I needed to in order to post a question. I'm asking exactly because I'm unsure, and it's up to the answers or lack thereof to provide or fail to provide solutions. The implication here seems to be that the question I asked is itself illogical or strange, which I don't believe it is at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many file types are actually pretty complex, sort of mini-file systems in themselves. For any software to detect healthy/valid vs. corrupt/invalid files it would need to understand each file type it supports in detail. So for a tool to support 20 file types is like writing a file *recovery* tool with support for 20 file systems.

Now, if we'd zoom into one file type, for instance JPEG, it is not rocket science to write some code that checks if the file is structurally okay. So sort of how chkdsk looks at the file system. Chkdsk checks if a file system is okay or consistent but it has no idea about the actual data.

To check actual data of a JPEG file the validation tool needs to either look at the JPEG encoded data and see if it appears valid, or it needs to look at the actual image and determine if it looks okay.

A JPEG can  become corrupt due to one bit in the encoded data 'flipping' which I demonstrate here:

[image]

This bit happens to disrupt the decoder resulting in half the image disappearing. This could be easily detected using code. However this image will 'render' just fine and is thus harder to detect as beng corrupt:

[image]

If we consider a file type like mp4, we're dealing with a standard that offers a lot of 'freedom'. Core component is the 'atom', common atoms are ftyp, mdat and moov and often these atoms appear in this order. Usually an mp4 starts with the ftyp atom so I know of some recovery tools that check if a mp4 file it detected using the MFT is intact or not by verifying it starts with the ftyp atom. Now this is a very simple check and will mainly tell if a file is not intact.

At least, that's the theory, because I'va ran into playable mp4 files that start with an mdat atom.

Which brings us to the next problem with file validation: false positives and negatives. So tool claims a file is corrupt while it isn't and the other way around.

That all being said, some possible solutions:

Check JPEGs: https://coderslagoon.com/#/product/badpeggy

Check videos: Use ffmpeg and batch file (I can't vouch for the batch file, make your own):

```
u/echo off
set "filter=%1"
if [%filter%]==[] (set "filter=*.mp4")
for /R %%a in (%filter%) do call :doWork "%%a"
PAUSE
exit /B
:doWork
C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -v error -i %1 -f null - > "%~1.log" 2>&1
```

To use:

`checkvideo.bat [filter]`, if you don't give one filter, will get '*.mp4'.
Example: checkvideo.bat checkvideo.bat *.avi

You can probably use a similar method with zip files, see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3954505/15697799

But for pretty much each file type you want to check you need to find an app that will try opening a file, that can be batched (accepts command line arguments and can log errors)

Answer (score 4):

> **What solutions are currently out there to allow me to search for corrupted files and remove them from my recovered hard-drives?**

None.

This is partly because "all major formats" is not a well defined list.

You could make a list of the formats of interest to you, for each format identify a command that will check it. The command might be a conversion to another format where the output is to a null file or one that is subsequently deleted. Then write a script to apply appropriate command to all files, detect failure and delete or separate files that fail.